# How to dismiss System Authorization Alerts in XCUITest in iOS 12

Tags: swift, ios12, xcuitest

I still have trouble to react in my XCUITest with system alerts like "authorization request for photo library". I tried the following code snippets. But none of them work. Any ideas?

**UI Interruption Monitor**

```swift
addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "System alert") { (alerts) -> Bool in
    if alert.buttons["OK"].exists {
        alert.buttons["OK"].tap()
    }
    return true
}

XCUIApplication().sheets.buttons["Aufnahme"].firstMatch.tap()
```

**Waiting with NSPredicate**

```swift
XCUIApplication().sheets.buttons["Aufnahme"].firstMatch.tap()

let existsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
let expectation = XCTNSPredicateExpectation(predicate: existsPredicate, object: app.alerts.firstMatch)
let result = XCTWaiter.wait(for: [expectation], timeout: timeout)
if result == .completed {
    app.alerts.firstMatch.tap()
} else {
    print("### TIMEOUT ###")
}
```

**Waiting for Existence**

```swift
XCUIApplication().sheets.buttons["Aufnahme"].firstMatch.tap()
app.alerts.firstMatch.waitForExistence(timeout: 10)
```

**Sprinboard Solution**

This solution is based on the post from [Lepidopteron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609704/xctestcase-with-auth0-how-to-dismiss-security-alert-xxxx-wants-to-use-auth0?answertab=votes#tab-top). It works in general but seems to be pretty slow (see my log below). At t=14.51s I tap the button "open photo library. Then the system alert directly appears in my app. But then everything seems to freeze for around 70 seconds.
At t = 78.08 the `setPermission()` function is called.

Did someone experience similar behavior?

```sh
### OPEN PHOTO LIBRARY
    t =    14.51s Tap "Aufnahmen" Button
    t =    14.51s     Wait for bone.self.TargetShooter to idle
    t =    14.56s     Find the "Aufnahmen" Button
    t =    14.62s         Check for interrupting elements affecting "Aufnahmen" Button
    t =    14.84s     Synthesize event
    t =    14.98s     Wait for bone.self.TargetShooter to idle
    t =    75.08s         App animations complete notification not received, will attempt to continue.
### START AUTHORITATION PROCESS
    t =    75.08s Get number of matches for: Descendants matching type Alert
    t =    75.12s     Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 13439
    t =    75.16s     Find: Descendants matching type Alert
### ALLOW SYSTEM ALERT
    t =    75.16s Find the Alert
    t =    75.16s     Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 13439
    t =    75.23s     Find: Descendants matching type Alert
    t =    75.23s     Find: Element at index 0
    t =    75.23s Get number of matches for: Descendants matching type Button
    t =    75.29s     Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 13439
    t =    75.33s     Find: Descendants matching type Alert
    t =    75.33s     Find: Element at index 0
    t =    75.33s     Find: Descendants matching type Button
    t =    75.33s Checking existence of `Button`
    t =    75.33s     Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 13439
    t =    75.39s     Find: Descendants matching type Alert
    t =    75.39s     Find: Element at index 0
    t =    75.39s     Find: Descendants matching type Button
    t =    75.39s     Find: Element at index 1
    t =    75.39s Find the Button
    t =    75.39s     Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 13439
    t =    75.45s     Find: Descendants matching type Alert
    t =    75.45s     Find: Element at index 0
    t =    75.45s     Find: Descendants matching type Button
    t =    75.45s     Find: Element at index 1
    t =    75.59s Tap "OK" Button
    t =    75.59s     Wait for com.apple.springboard to idle
    t =    75.65s     Find the "OK" Button
    t =    75.65s         Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 13439
    t =    75.72s         Find: Descendants matching type Alert
    t =    75.72s         Find: Element at index 0
    t =    75.72s         Find: Descendants matching type Button
    t =    75.72s         Find: Element at index 1
    t =    75.83s         Check for interrupting elements affecting "OK" Button
    t =    75.88s             Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 13439
    t =    75.93s             Find: Descendants matching type Alert
    t =    75.98s     Synthesize event
    t =    76.13s     Wait for com.apple.springboard to idle
### END AUTHORITATION PROCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works in my code, try it:

```
var photoAccessGranted = XCTestExpectation(description: "photo access")


addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "system permissions") { (alert) -> Bool in
        print("1) addUIInterruptionMonitor:\(alert)")

        if alert.staticTexts["Put here the text that you get in the alert"].exists { // Photo permission
            alert.buttons["OK"].tap()
            self.photoAccessGranted.fulfill()
        }
```